# Алгоритм для умножения разреженных матриц

Tags: c++, алгоритм, матрицы

Изучая разреженные матрицы (у которых большинство элементов не 0, а допустим x, и которые организованы в виде списка тринарных элементов, состояющих из двух индексов и значения), достаточно легко подобрать алгоритм для умножения двух матриц и подсчитать его сложность, которая будет `о(n^3)` при матрицах `n*n`, если `x = 0`.

По моему анализу, той же эффективности можно достичь при `х != 0`, но алгоритм будет намного сложнее.

Смысл примерно в том же, - мы циклично получаем строку, для каждой строки получаем каждый столбец, но сложность самого алгоритма уже зависит от того, как мы работаем с теми столбцами и строками, которые либо полностью наполненны значением х, либо частично. То есть, можно в отдельности считать количество элементов которые дадут `х^2` и прибавлять их к нынешний сумме (новому элементу на месте i,j). 
Также в отдельности считать произведение х и реальных значений или вдоль строки или вдоль столбца пока не дойдем до индекса, где есть оба реальных значения, произведение которых нужно добавить к считаемой сумме.

То есть формула сумма для `k от 0 до n (i,k)*(k,j)` становится не линеарной.

Кто нибудь понял примерно тот алгоритм, который я прикинул? 
У меня не получается написать даже его примерный псевдокод.

Может кто-нибудь знает хорошие источники по данной теме или может накидать этот алгоритм в наиболее простом виде здесь?

Answer (score 2):

Понял ли я алгоритм? нет.

> Изучая разреженные матрицы (у которых большинство элементов **не 0, а
>   допустим x**, и которые ... которая будет о(n^3) при матрицах n*n,
>   если **x=0**

Как-то странно. Не 0, но вот при равном 0... При равных 0 элементах сложность точно `O(n^2)` - записать `n^2` нулей.

Да и `O(n^3)` - это для произведения любых (не разреженных) матриц при применении классической схемы умножения...

А почитать - то классика (хоть и древняя): **Писсанецки С.** *Технология разреженных матриц* - в Интернете можно найти. Есть еще такая Matrix Template Library, можно посмотреть ее, но это очень профессиональный код, там просто так, с налета, не разобраться.